# Change order of store-views in multistore setup in ADMIN?

Tags: magento2, store-view

I have 3 store views ie **ENGLISH**, **GERMAN** and **FRENCH** language.

When I **edit a setting or product details page**, store views comes in `orders/positions`  as displayed in below image:

[image]

I want to change their  `order/position` like below ie **ENGLISH on top**

[image]

I have already **tried setting order of store views** in **Store View Information**